# JQuery hidden objects

Tags: jquery

Ok guys, I have edited the question so that you can understand. I have 10 images and their respective name in paragraph. So, you have 10 images and 10 paragraphs. As the images are different, and of course, have different names, I cannot use a class. So, I used an ID to one image and another ID to its name.

The user will click on one image, it wil hide and its respective name as well. When the user will click another image, it will hide and its respective name again until everything is  hidden. I could use a class for one image and its respective name, but the user has the right to click only on the image and not on the name. Just like a hidden object game!

I will give you an example of one image below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#image1').click(function() {
        $(this).hide('slow');
        $('#name').hide('slow');
    });

    if ($('#image1').is(':hidden')) {
        alert('Hello');
    }
});​
```

Bear in mind, I changed the example so that you can understand. As you see, if the user is clicking on image, its respective name also is hidden. Both of them are hidden. Then, I verify if the image is hidden, an alert box will display. The image and its name do hide, but the alert box is not displaying... And I have to verify if the image is hidden, so that the alert box is displayed.

Comment: You forgot a quote on your page in the load function! And you should probably stick both the if and the load inside your click function, as right now all it does is check if the image is visible on page load.

Comment: look well it is here.. the hidden validation is not working

Comment: It most certainly is, on initial page load?

Comment: You want each image to hide itself individually on click, then when they are all hidden, load the page. right?

Comment: well, i put what you said but in vain.i have to verify if all images are hidden so that it can load the page. the example above is just on two images but there are more images with different IDs as they are different..

Comment: @user1780468 Don't you have a way of selecting all images? For example if they all have the css class `link` you could use $('img.link') as the selector in the answer I posted.

Comment: Ok, suppose I have 10 images with different IDs, each time the user will click on one, it will hide. Once all are hidden, then then the other page will load in a div. All must be hidden first.. The example above is just on one image..

Comment: @user1780468 No, it's not. Please check the examples added in the answer.

Comment: I modified the question, read it again to understand..

Comment: Are you aware that when you click on #image1, you never call if ($('#image1').is(':hidden')){...} snippet?!!!

Comment: Ill post answer to show you what im talking about

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
$(document).ready (function() {
    $('#image1').click(function() {
        $(this).hide('slow');
        $('#image2').hide('slow');

        $('#div').load(page.html');
    });
});
```

Comment: No, I will add more images, so I must verify all must be hidden then load... And the images are different, with different IDs. So, a verification of them if they are hidden I think is appropriate..

Answer (score 0):

This code binds the same handler to the click event, which hides both images and loads the page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#image1, #image2').click(function() {
        $('#image1, #image2').hide();
        $('#div').load('page.html');        
    });
});​
```

As mentioned in the comments you could devise a way of selecting all the related images. For example wrapping them in a div or adding a class to identify them.

Take a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/HZ9hN/1/) and [this](http://jsfiddle.net/HZ9hN/2/) fiddle for an example on how to do this.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Read above, I explained it first for responding

Answer (score 0):

If you are hidden on the click, and the click will always hide both, you may have this as your script:

```
$(document).ready (function() {
    $('#image1, #image2').click(function() {
      $('#image1, #image2').hide();

      $('#div').load('page.html', function() {
        alert('Load was performed.');
      });        
    });
});​
```

Are you sure you are returning a correct content from you 'page.html'?

Comment: yes.. i even tested it with an alert in place of the AJAX to see, but even the alert is not working

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be something like that if i correctly understand your question.

So, if i get it, you can do something like that, assuming you add a class (lets say myimgclass) to all your images you want to check:

Your code should be something like that if i correctly understand your question.

So, if i get it, you can do something like that, assuming you add a class (lets say myimgclass) to all your images you want to check:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.myimgclass').click(function() {
        //hide >>name here<<

        $(this).hide('slow', function() {
            var check = true;
            $('.myimgclass').each(function() {                
                //we check if image is visible, if so we stop here
                if($(this).is(':visible')) {
                    check = false;
                    return;
                }
            });
            if(check) alert('Hello');
        });
    });

});​
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/s7FXR/

Comment: But there are different names.. All images have different names, thus only the respective name should be hide if its respective image is hidden, this is why I am using ID here... Your code addresses only to one name for all images.. Just imagine a hidden object game..

Comment: Read the new version, I edited it again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147724/jquery-hidden-objects-check