# JQuery hidden objects check

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JQuery hidden objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146045/jquery-hidden-objects)

I am posting the issue again as the first time, many did not understand. Ok, I will change my question again, removing the confusion part.

I have 4 images with different IDs. I cannot use class here as each image is related to another thing, so forget class here to avoid confusion. What is going to happen, when the user clicks on each image it will hide. So, after clicking on 4 images, the 4 will be hidden of course.

I want that after the 4 images are hidden, an alert box is displayed.  Please, I have to include a code to verify if all images are hidden here, do not ask me why to avoid confusing again. The images are hiding once clicked, but the only issue is the alert box is not displayed after the 4 images are hidden. Code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#image1').click(function() {
        $(this).hide('slow');
    });

    $('#image2').click(function() {
        $(this).hide('slow');
    });

    $('#image3').click(function() {
        $(this).hide('slow');
    });

    $('#image4').click(function() {
        $(this).hide('slow');
    });

    if ($('#image1, #image2, #image3, #image4').is(':hidden')) {
        alert('kkk');
    }
});​
```

Comment: Your if statement only runs once, which just so happens to be before ANY of your images gets clicked. therefore it is not possible for your alert to happen. It must be inside of the click events. Keep in mind that they will not be immediately :hidden because of `'slow'` If you remove `slow` and move the if statement to inside of each click event, it will work. Just as explained before.

Answer (score 1):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TAmNX/)

You need to create a `function` to do the check as a **callback** for the `click` `event` is fired for the respective `image`. The way you have it, is after the `click` `events` are bound it runs the `if` statement once. Doing it the way below will fix that...

```
$(document).ready (function() {

   $('#image1').click(function() {
      $(this).hide('slow', checkImages);
   });

   $('#image1').click(function() {
      $(this).hide('slow', checkImages);
   });

   $('#image2').click(function() {
       $(this).hide('slow', checkImages);
   });

   $('#image3').click(function() {
       $(this).hide('slow', checkImages);
   });


});

function checkImages(){
   if ($('[id^=image]:visible').length == 0) {
     alert('I am a bunny');
   }

}
```

Comment: `checkImages` will happen before the clicked image becomes `:hidden` due to `'slow'`

Comment: this is what i want like you are doing in JSFiddle. However, I cannot use this as I have other things to do when the image is clicked. I did not mention it in the example to avoid confusion. I want to do it like this:

function checkAllHidden(){
  if ($('#image1, #image2, #image3, #image4'):visible').length == 0) {
    alert('I am a bunny');

well, im getting syntax error here.. bracket perhaps?

Comment: `if ($('#image1, #image2, #image3, #image4'):visible')` is the problem.. should be `if ($('#image1, #image2, #image3, #image4').is(':visible').length == 0)`

Comment: damn again, it does not appear the alert box... weird...

Comment: I am not sure what your issue is, clearly it works for me in the fiddle.

Comment: are you serious? can you paste the link here? its not http://jsfiddle.net/angelali2013/TAmNX/1/

Comment: dude, i told you i cannot use your method in the function as i have to do other things when it hides. i did not mention it in the example. look this link, this is how i want to do it, but the alert box is not displayed.. http://jsfiddle.net/angelali2013/TAmNX/1/

Comment: So you're going to get mouthy with someone who is providing you free help. Interesting, let me know how that works out for you.

Comment: hey man im not getting mouthy... i did mention it, i am not at fault if you have not noticed it... even that sorry

Comment: @user1780468, I am glad you think you're not at fault. If you know so much, then figure out yourself.

Comment: now who is getting mouthy here? So, if you don't want to help in this last part, then ok dude, thank you!

Comment: @user1780468 you need to change `is` to `filter` - is returns a boolean

Comment: yes, but it is executing 4 alert boxes after hiding of each image. i want only one alert box to display..

Comment: well i think it is working now..thank you   if i get some issues, i will come back later...

Answer (score 1):

Try this - combine all your function into just one.. since they all do the same thing

```
$('#image1,#image2,#image3,#image4').click(function() {
    // hide current clicked
    $(this).hide('slow',function(){
        // check if all the images are hidden
        if ($('#image1,#image2,#image3,#image4').filter(':hidden').length == 4) {
            alert('I am a bunny');
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: or `.filter(":visible").length === 0`

Comment: This will not work because when the filter runs, image will still be hiding

Comment: @Adrian I edited it to be in the callback function

Comment: Also, your solution assumes OP will always have 4 elements and will fail for 3 or 5. Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can eliminate repetition by using the selector for all elements that start with `image`.

`$("[id^=image]")` selects all elements whose id starts with `image`.

Then you have to provide the hide callback function, so that it only runs when animation ends:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("[id^=image]").click(function() {
        $(this).hide('slow', function() {
            if ($('[id^=image]:visible').length == 0) {
                alert('I am a bunny');
            }
        });
    });
});​
```

Comment: I like this selector much better... +1

Comment: @Gabe Sorry about that, I resent it as a mistake :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the callback of the hide method and move your if statement to inside the click event so it happens on every click.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var images = $("#image1, #image2, #image3, #image4")
    images.click(function(){
        $(this).hide('slow',function(){
            if (images.filter(":visible").length === 0) {
                alert("worky");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Nice solution here, I like the cached selector. +1

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want, with simplification:

```
        $('#image1, #image2, #image3, #image4').click(function () {
            $(this).hide('slow', alertIfHidden);
        });

        function alertIfHidden() {
            if (!($('#image1, #image2, #image3, #image4').is(':visible'))) {
                alert('I am a bunny');
            }
        }
```

Note that you need to check that none of the images are visible, vs your original code that returned true if at least one image was hidden.

Comment: yes but it is executing the alert box each time is clicked. i want the alert to display once all the images have been hidden..

Comment: I see the alert box once at the end.  Perhaps there is something else in your environment influencing it.

Answer (score -1):

You did not check whether all are hidden each time the image was hidden. There are a lot of code refactor possible here

```
$(document).ready (function() {

$('#image1').click(function() {
$(this).hide('slow');
checkAllHidden();
});

$('#image1').click(function() {
$(this).hide('slow');
checkAllHidden();
});

$('#image2').click(function() {
$(this).hide('slow');
checkAllHidden();
});

$('#image3').click(function() {
$(this).hide('slow');
checkAllHidden();
});


});
function checkAllHidden(){
  if ($('#image1, #image2, #image3, #image4').is(':hidden')) {
    alert('I am a bunny');
  }
}
```

Comment: `checkAllHidden` will happen before the clicked image is `:hidden` due to `'slow'`

Comment: ok it is working, but cant I add an effect? the slow effect was nice...lol

Comment: there is an isue, i want to execute the alert box after all the images have been hidden and not each time the user is clicked...

Comment: i have not voted down, perhaps others did...